# fixed length file issue

Tags: text-processing

few records in fixed length file are split into two records
The file looks some thing similar to below.  The third record is split into two records.  How can I remove '\r' from the end and move the fourth row up and merge with third row.

Sample File:

```
Firstrow\n
Secondrow\n
Third\r\n
Row\n
Fourthrow\n
Fifthrow\n
```

Final Result needed:

```
Firstrow\n
secondrow\n
Thirdrow\n
Fourthrow\n
Fifthrow\n
```

Comment: In your question, it's a little tricky to visually compare the text from the input with the final output - could you use some random words rather than strings of random letters? I think people will be more likely to give you an answer if you do this.

Comment: Please see https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/formatting for how to format your question and also add your own attempt to solve the problem. See [ask] and look at existing questions that have been upvoted and answered for examples of how to ask a good question.

Comment: what do you mean by a "_fixed length file_"? and how that has any relevant to your problem?!

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
sed '/\r/{N; s/\r\n//}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

using awk you can play with the output record separator depending on the line

```
awk '{ORS = sub(/\r$/,"") ? "" : RS};1' file > temp && mv temp file
```

Or , using perl where we remove the CRLF pair

```
$ perl -pi -e 's/\r\n//' file
```

Comment: None of them are working.  It is not moving fourth record and appending to third record.

Comment: Made in place edits now. Check now.